# CMD Download file one liner, escaping space character?

Tags: powershell, cmd

I have a class assessment to create a python http server and download a file with cmd, this is the command I use:

`(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile(\"http://10.10.10.10:4444/file.exe\"^,\"C:\Windows\System32\file.exe\")`

and this is the output:

`'(New-Object' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.`

it looks like CMD treats the space char as a args separator. I already try out these symbols to escape it \ / ^ ` but none of them works. What should I do?

Comment: Are you running this PowerShell command from the cmd console, or from the PowerShell console?

Comment: Why cmd? Is that required by the assignment? Since you use a powershell command, why not run it in powershell directly?

Answer (score 0):

I see you are running it from Cmd, so run:

```
Powershell -c "& {(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://10.10.10.10:4444/file.exe','C:\Windows\System32\file.exe')}"
```